# Workbook.SheetChange event handler lost after switching workbooks

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

Can anyone explain the following Event behavior in an Excel VSTO Add-in?

I set up a Workbook SheetChange event as below:

```
Workbook wb = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook;

wb.SheetChange += workbook_Change;
```

And the event handler simply alerts when it is hit.

```
public static void workbook_Change(Object sh, Range Target)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Book Change HIT", "Book Change: " + (sh as Worksheet).Name);
    return;
}
```

The event is firing as expected when modifying cells in the active workbook, up until the user switches to a different workbook in the same Excel session.
After switching between workbooks, the change event is lost and is not fired again.

When changing between sheets in the same workbook, or switching between separate Excel instances, the behavior is as expected and the event keeps firing.

My expectation is the event should remain attached to the workbook and not get unloaded or lost or whatever is happening when switching between workbooks.

As a work-around, I created an Application.WorkbookActivate handler, which will re-register the change event handler whenever the workbook is re-activated.
This seems to resolve the issue, however I am still curious why the Sheetchange event handler is lost when switching workbooks?

Can anyone provide some insight?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wasn't able to find a solution to the Workbook event getting lost, I believe this still happens, my work-around to re-register the event handler also didn't work reliably. A better work-around is to register the sheet change handler against the Application instead.

```
Application.SheetChange += new Excel.AppEvents_SheetChangeEventHandler(Application_SheetChange);
```

This event fires against every worksheet/workbook, but I am able to then reference the selected Worksheet using

```
Worksheet theSheet = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveSheet;
```

I hope this helps anyone else with the same issue.